# DNS lookup with different Port

Tags: dns, routing

I have 2 interface.

- interface_1 ip address 10.192.0.1 ---
- interface_2 ip address 192.168.10.2 gw 192.168.10.1 --- default gateway.

Not I want to pass my url lookup (keeping 4.2.2.2) with interface_1 (it can have the gateway 10.192.0.2) n all internet traffic by interface 2.

Any option?

Comment: looks like a near-duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/multigateway-routing-for-specific-src-port except DNS on UDP port 53 rather than ssh on TCP port 22.